# How to pass variable values for oracle connection in python

Tags: python, django, database, oracle, cx-oracle

Im able to connect to Oracle Db successfully when i hardcode the Db details like "    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("uname/pass@192.168.xxx.yyy:port/db")" but how to pass the variable values to connect to the db?

I tried some like this.

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("{}/{}@{}:{}/{}".format(uname,password,IP,port,db))
```

which is not working as expected so please share some thought on this to make it work.

```
def knowcobrand(request):
    value_type = request.POST.get('CobranSelection')
    cobrand_value = request.POST.get('cobrand')
    env = request.POST.get('NewEnvName')
    print(value_type)
    print(cobrand_value)
    print(env)
    # feed = Environments.objects.get(Q(Env_name__icontains=env))
    # print(feed.user_name)
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("app/app@192.168.xxx.yy:port/db")
```

I want to use the variable's value of value_type and env for Db connection

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You should probably run through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/), it will explain the basics of Django and using the ORM

[You should configure your database connection in your settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases)

[There is a specific example for oracle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/databases/#id11)

You can now use the Django ORM ([after running migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/))

If you want a raw cursor for the database you can still use Django for this like so

```
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor() as c:
    c.execute(...)
```

Comment: I wanted to connect to sqllite db to store personal info about a user and Oracle DB for actual operation. I have already have sqllite db connection details in settings.py DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

Comment: You can have multiple databases in Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: just for your understanding let me describe my use case....i take oracle db details from user and store it sqllite file and then i fetch the same details and connect to oracle so could you please help me in this

Comment: You should configure 2 database connections in your settings. Then you can use them with your models like so `Model.objects.using('key_in_database_settings').all()`. If you do not include the `using` part then Django will use the default database connection

Comment: but again i'm hardcoding the Db details in settings.py...Cant i directly read Db details like def knowcobrand(request):
    env = request.POST.get('NewEnvName')
    feed = Environments.objects.get(Q(Env_name__icontains=env))
     print(feed.user_name) then pass details like feed.user_name to connect